# How to set page icon in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set page icon. There is `App` class of PCL below.

```
public App()
{
    CustomMainPage mainPage = new CustomMainPage(); 
    NavigationPage rootPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
    this.MainPage = rootPage;
}
```

What I tried to do?

```
NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(mainPage, "icon.png");
```

The second approach.

```
NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "icon.png");
```

The third approach.

```
NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(rootPage, "icon.png");
```

File `icon.png` is situated into `Resources/drawable`.

And finally I decided to implement my custom renderer for the `NavigationPage` in Xamarin Forms. `NavigationPage` is setted to `MainPage` property into `App` class of PCL.

I created `DroidNavigationRenderer` class into Android project.

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(DroidNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace App1.Droid.DroidRenderers
{
    public class DroidNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;
            actionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        }
    }
}
```

But `actionBar` is always returns as null.
What I do wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ContentPage`, you have the `Icon` property.

You can set it this way

```
Icon = Device.OnPlatform("Menu", "ic_fa_bars.png", "Assets/Icons/reload.png");
```

Comment: It does not work. I simplified my `App` class to `this.MainPage = new ContentPage { Icon = Device.OnPlatform("Menu", "icon.png", "Assets/Icons/reload.png"), BackgroundImage = "lightWood.png" };` Also it does not work. I don't know what is the problem. Maybe my custom icon influence on it. It is `png` image (52x72px). It is situated into `MyProject/Resources/drawable/icon.png` But background image is displayed.

Comment: I think you need to have the NavigationPage in order to show the icon.

Comment: Hi @JosephKatzman: have you manage to do this?
I search a way to display a logo with SetTitleIcon() only on a single page.
This works fine on iOS, but on Android: the logo is displayed on each page...

Answer (score 0):

What is your CustomMainPage class? If I have TabbedPage and set one of its child I do it this way:

```
var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    navigationPage.Icon = "services.png";
}
```

hope it helps